# How remove dot after section number in ToC with babel's spanish?

Tags: table-of-contents, punctuation, babel, spanish

I'm using the `book` document class and the `babel` package with the `spanish` option, I have a ToC like this:

> 1. **CHAPTER NAME**
>      1.1. SECTION NAME
>         1.1.1. Subsection name
>                1.1.1.1. *Subsubsection name*

How can I remove the dot after sections numbers, tables numbers on LoT and figure numbers on LoF?.

P.S.: The Chapter number should have a dot.

Here a MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoftables

\listoffigures

\chapter{CHAPTER NAME}

\section{SECTION NAME}

\subsection{Subsection name}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection name}

\begin{table}
    My table
    \caption{Table}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
    My figure
    \caption{Figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note that I'm using the code:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\makeatother
```

to remove the dot after sections number in the document.

Comment: Thanks for the MWE; I took the liberty and removed some things from it that aren't relevant to your problem, in order to make it somewhat more of a real *minimal* working example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Spanish module for `babel` is responsible for this, probably following some directive of the authority on the language. There is an additional option for disabling it:

```
\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman,es-nosectiondot]{babel}
```

See section 2.3 in the documentation for the Spanish option (`texdoc spanish` or [here on TeXdoc.net](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/spanish/spanish.pdf)).

There will be no need to act on `\@seccntformat`.

In order to keep the period after the chapter number (although I don't see why), patch the `\@chapter` command:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@chapter{\numberline{\thechapter}}{\numberline{\thechapter.}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks egreg, this is a very good solution. But removes the dot after the Chapter number in TOC. How can I add a dot to this?

Comment: ...caused by a redefinition of `\numberline`: `\def\numberline#1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1\if&#1&\else.\fi\hfil}}` from the original `\def\numberline#1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1\hfil}}`

Comment: egreg thanks again, the dot after chapter number is a requirement of the format for my thesis. Thanks!

Comment: @osjerick doncherry removed the irrelevant packages from your example and did well. But remember: *never* pass the `pdftex` option to `graphicx` or `hyperref`.

Comment: @egreg when I use the code `es-nosectiondot` and `\patchcmd@chapter{\numberline{\thechapter}}{\numberline{\thechapter.}}{}{}`, the dot in LoF and LoT dissapears, i.e, I want `Table 1.` instead I have `Table 1` and it's same for `Figure 1`. Can you help me please?

Comment: @Joan Please, ask a new questions with the details.

Comment: @egreg - Please see my question here [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476036/remove-the-dot-after-section-number-in-toc-witouth-any-package)

Comment: option "es-nosectiondot". Thank you @egreg!