# Formatting counter in section, subsection and subsubsection

Tags: sectioning, formatting, numbering, babel

I want to show a counter with subsubsection-level headers and remove the final dot from the section counter, subsection and subsubsection (assuming you can assign a counter to subsubsection) by employing the `book` class, but without the help of packages. This is because I am creating my own class using the file `book.cls`.

More specifically I want

```
1.1 Section
1.1.1 Subsection
1.1.1.1 Subsubsection
```

instead of

```
1.1. Section
1.1.1. Subsection
1.1.1.1. Subsubsection
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Writing a class of one's own is tedious and requires some fundamental knowledge on LaTeX. You're trying to reinvent the wheel, most likely

Comment: @ChristianHupfer On the other hand, a lot of “advertisements” (introductory tutorials, etc) for LaTeX suggest that the way to modify the overall appearance of a document is to write your own class. So... users can hardly be blamed for trying to do exactly that.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Well, that's the fault of those other sources of course. It's however really blindsighted to believe that beginners of LaTeX can do it on their own. 99.99% can't. Period.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - But do we know whether Joan is a beginner? :-)

Comment: @Joan - Do take the spirit of Christian H's comments to heart: Many LaTeX packages have been around for a long time and are quite stable, meet specific formatting needs very well, and tend to be well debugged. Rather than re-invent the wheel, so to say, by coming up with your own code, you may want to look into what various packages can do for you and load some packages with judiciously chosen options. For sure, it makes little sense to ignore the capabilities of packages such as `geometry`, `amsmath` and `amssymb`, `caption`, `siunitx`, `natbib`, `hyperref`, or `cleveref`, to name but a few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote,

> I want to add a counter to the subsubsection [headers]

Just insert the instruction

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```

in the preamble. The default value of this counter for the `book` class is `2`, meaning that only `subsection` headers (and thus also `section` and `chapter` and `part` headers) get numbered.

If you want subsubsection-level headers to show up in the Table of Contents as well, you will also need to specify

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
```

in the preamble. (You can probably guess that the default value of this counter is `2`.)

---

You also wrote,

> [I want to] remove the final dot from the section counter, subsection and subsubsection

The format *without* a final dot is actually the default in the `book` document class. In a comment, you've indicated that you employ the `babel` package with the language option `spanish`. Indeed, this setting overrides the `book` default, i.e., it affixes dots to section, subsection, and subsubsection numbers. To override this language-specific setting, one needs to load the `babel` package with the additional option `es-nosectiondot`:

```
\usepackage[spanish,es-nosectiondot]{babel}
```

or, equivalently, write

```
\usepackage[spanish.nosectiondot]{babel}
```

For more information on this subject, see the posting [How to remove dot after section number in ToC with babel's spanish?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74111/5001) For more information on what the `spanish` language option of the `babel` package does and how the resulting, language-specific settings can be modified, type

```
texdoc babel-spanish
```

at a command prompt. The user guide document that will open up is written in Spanish -- no problem for you, right? :-)

---

An MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % default for book class: 2
\usepackage[spanish,es-nosectiondot]{babel} % suppress affixed dots
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\section{One.One}
\subsection{One.One.One}
\subsubsection{One.One.One.One}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not using any package other than babel, inputenc and fontenc, it's weird because all I did was collect the file code `book.cls`. Do you know in which part of the file can I verify this?

Comment: @Joan - Which language(s) do you employ with `babel`? And, which TeX distribution (and which vintage) do you use?

Comment: `spanish` for `babel` and `TeX Live`.

Comment: @Joan - Indeed, that setting will add a dot after section, subsection, and subsubsection numbers. I edited my answer to give an instruction on what to do -- basically, one also needs to pass the option `es-nosectiondot` to `babel`.

Comment: I just checked it and when I use the `babel` package with the `spanish` option the end dot appears in the counter format, but when I use the `babel` package with the `english` option then the final dot disappears...I do not know what to do.

Comment: @Joan - Did you notice how I updated my answer about two hours ago? In the updated answer, I recommend changing `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` to `\usepackage[spanish,es-nosectiondot]{babel}`. This gets rid of the dot that's affixed to section, subsection, and subsubsection numbers.